# TabBar pops when dragging back a no-Tabbed Bar VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIViewController` with a tab bar (regular) called `FirstVC`.

When I click on a button is `FirstVC`, `SecondVC` is being showed using `UINavigationController`.

`SecondVC` has no TabBar.

The problem is, that when I scroll back from my `SecondVC` to the `FirstVC`, the TabBar pops automatically above `SecondVC`, how can I fix that (image provided below)?

Thank you!

Image:

[image]

secondVC:

[image]

Comment: Is your `SecondVC` meant to be another tab in your `UINavigationController`? Or something that is presented via a segue?

Comment: @MattLeFleur I present the `SecondVC` like that:
`navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)`

Comment: In your picture it looks like your tab bar is still at the bottom. Could you perhaps provide another image for how the your `SecondVC` looks when scrolling back. Also how are you scrolling back? Using one of the buttons at the bottom, or using the back button on your `NavigationController`?

Comment: @MattLeFleur The TabBar is at the bottom and that's the point, it shown when I'm starting to drag back the view (dragging from the left part of the screen to the right, you can do that with `UINavigationController` without pushing a button). I've added a new image that's shows how the `SecondVC` looks like before starting to drag back

Comment: set tabbar hidden to YES in FirstVC's viewwilldisappear and set it back to NO in FirstVC's viewwillappear

Comment: @dopcn Still doesn't work

Comment: I want that the tabBar will be under `SecondVC` while dragging and not on top of it

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the image of your storyboard?